# How to model an accelerometer measurements on a car wheel?

Tags: gravity, homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration

I am working on kinematically modelling an accelerometer on a car wheel.

When working on the initial conditions, I am confused whether or not I should use the gravitational acceleration since there is a normal force reaction counteracting. I.e should 
a = [a0, 0 , -g]

Thanks for the help :)
Yosef

**My Go at it:**
What I was thinking of, is that in case I was modelling a point on the wheel, the gravity would not be considered. However when modelling the measurement of an accelerometer I should consider the acceleration. Probably I will need to shift to the equations of motions, which will make the whole story even more difficult.

Comment: is the speed of the car changing?

Comment: What does the instrument read if you place in on the bench top? When you flip it over? Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Also, what do you mean by "on a car wheel"?  Where exactly is the accelerometer attached?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for asking. The accelerometer is attached on the tire at a radius r from the center of the wheel that is part of car. The car can be moving at a constant speed or accelerating. I doing my thesis on measuring the wheel's inclination while driving.

Comment: Is it still vague?